# Why does Powershell search every directory within one's $PATH for a PSConsoleHostReadLine file?

Tags: windows, powershell

all!

I noticed that Powershell, or more specifically, pasting and tab-completing within Powershell, was a lot slower on my machine after upgrading to v3 from v2. I opened up **procmon** to see  what was going on, only to find out that *every* attempt to tab-complete or paste anything triggers Powershell to find various permutations of the file provided in the subject. I have some network folders in my $PATH and walking through those folders every time I paste something seems non-ideal.

It seems that this file allows Powershell to behave more like Bash. While this is absolutely FANTASTIC and I'm looking forward to abusing this feature in the very near future, is there any way to configure Powershell such that it only attempts to find this file in *one* directory?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PSConsoleHostReadLine is actually a function. If PoSH can't find a method, alias, or anything else executable with that name, it falls back to it's default 'cooked' readline with editing, etc.

To redefine it, create a function:

```
function PSConsoleHostReadline {
    [Console]::Readline()
}
```

As written, this method disables editing, etc. Write your own insane magic to do whatever you wish.

I'm guessing it's searching all the extra locations due to Powershell 3 having "Module Auto Load" which checks for a function in all locations known in the ENV:PSModulePath, and auto-loads the module which contains said method.

Answer (score 0):

This was an oversight in V3.  V4 will only search for functions or aliases - it won't search for external exes when looking for PSConsoleHostReadline.

If you're looking for a bash like experience - check out https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine